# Python 3 json.loads - json.decoder error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a json but it doesn't work.
I remove the try and except in my code so you can see the Error Massege.

```
import sqlite3
import json
import codecs

conn = sqlite3.connect('geodata.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Locations')
fhand = codecs.open('where.js','w', "utf-8")
fhand.write("myData = [\n")
count = 0
for row in cur :
    data = str(row[1])
    print (data)
    print (type(data))
    #try:
    js = json.loads(data)
    #except: continue

    if not('status' in js and js['status'] == 'OK') : continue

    lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    if lat == 0 or lng == 0 : continue
    where = js['results'][0]['formatted_address']
    where = where.replace("'","")
    try :
        print (where, lat, lng)

        count = count + 1
        if count > 1 : fhand.write(",\n")
        output = "["+str(lat)+","+str(lng)+", '"+where+"']"
        fhand.write(output)
    except:
        continue

fhand.write("\n];\n")
cur.close()
fhand.close()
print (count, "records written to where.js")
print ("Open where.html to view the data in a browser")
```

My problem is that 
`js = json.loads(data)`
can't parse it for some reason and I get the following exception:

```
 "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
```

I thought it becuase the data type but its doing a weird thing.
I'm asking for type(data) and I'm getting str type, but when I print data I get Byte type.

Full output for the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Courses Online/Coursera/Using Databases with Python/geodata/geodump.py", line 17, in <module>
    js = json.loads(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
b'{\n   "results" : [\n      {\n         "address_components" : [\n            {\n  ...... long json line...... 
<class 'str'>
```

I also try to use decode("utf-8") on data , but I'm getting the following Error: `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Answer (score 1):

```
js = json.loads(data.decode('utf8'))
```

solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting a `bytes` value to a string the wrong way here:

```
data = str(row[1])
```

You forced it to be a `str()` object, but for `bytes` objects that'll *include* the `b` prefix and quotes, because `bytes` objects don't have a `__str__` method, only `__repr__` so you get a debug representation.

Decode the row *without* converting to a string:

```
data = row[1].decode('utf8')
```

You really shouldn't hand-craft JSON / Javascript output in your code either. Just use `json.dumps()`; if you *must* use per-row streaming, you can still use `json.dump()` to create each list entry:

```
import sqlite3
import json

conn = sqlite3.connect('geodata.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Locations')

with open('where.js', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fhand:
    fhand.write("myData = [\n")
    for count, row in enumerate(row):
        try:
            js = json.loads(row[1].decode('utf8'))
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            print('Could not decode a row: ', row[1])
            continue

        if js.get('status') != 'OK':
            continue

        lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
        lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
        if not (lat and lng):
            continue

        where = js['results'][0]['formatted_address']
        where = where.replace("'", "")
        print (where, lat, lng)

        if count: fhand.write(",\n")
        json.dump([lat, lng, where], fhand)

fhand.write("\n];\n")
```

This uses plain `open()` (in Python 3, there is never a need to use `codecs.open()`), uses the file as a context manager, and adds in `enumerate()` to track if you have the first row processed yet.